# jQuery Mobile Page Transition removes CSS Styles

Tags: jquery-mobile, transition

I have a strange problem with jQuery Mobile page transitions.

Demo can be found here: 
http://www.dev.theorie24.ch/mobile_index.php

If you click on "ANMELDEN" the new page gets loaded, but without the background gradient and some other styles missing.

After refreshing the new page, it looks fine. But then, if you go back (browser back button or arrow to the left on top), the first page gets displayed with some styles messed up.

What is happening here? How can I enforce the correct display of the whole page after the transition?

EDIT:
After the page transition, this is how the DOM looks like:

[image]

The body-tag actually closes much too early. This can't be right. Is that a bug in jQuery Mobile?

Thanks a lot!
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that in your second html file `data-role` attribute applied to the body. 
Try to wrap the content with `div` element with `data-role="page"`, like so:

```
<html>
...
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```